# Adding new line delimitter instead of Comma between Elements except the First Element in java

Tags: java, list, delimiter

I want to add a new Line Delimitter between the elements of a List in Java which is Comma delimitted, How can I be able to achieve this?
for Eg: if my list is `[AROl, JACOB, JOSEPH]`

Can I be able to Achieve similay to like

```
[ AROL
 JACOB
 JOSEPH
]
```

Comment: replace comma with??

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: but what do you mean elements comma delimited in a list?

Comment: [with java 8 you could use the StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ updated the Question

Comment: *what have you tried?*

Comment: `boolean first = true;`
`StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();`

`for (Map.Entry<MyClass.Key,String> entry : data.entrySet()) {`
    `if (first) {`
        first = false;
   ` } else {`
      `  builder.append("\n"); // Or whatever break you want`
`    }`
`    builder.append(entry.key())`
           `.append(": ")`
          ` .append(entry.value());`
`}`

Comment: and what does not work for you in that code? *Tell* us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the power of java 8 you can do a [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-):

```
List<String> myist = Arrays.asList("AROl", "JACOB", "JOSEPH");
String result = String.join("\n", myist);

System.out.println(result);
```

the result will be

```
AROl
JACOB
JOSEPH
```

Comment: But in Microsoft Excel The new line character goes unnoticed, in Google Sheets and other software it is recognized?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("AROL", "JACOB","JOSEPH");
String result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n ", "[ ", "\n]"));
System.out.println(result);
```

result:

```
[ AROL
 JACOB
 JOSEPH
]
```